# SQL - Get Month Name and SUM() of every month

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following task to perform on a table:

- *Show the months name*, the quantity of orders and the total value of
  order for each month

and I have a diagram for my current tables
[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYfKy.png)

I'm sorry that it's in a foreign language but I'll translate.

- Pedido stands for Order
- Produto for Product Cliente for Client and
- Item_Pedido for Order_Item

I've tried joining the tables and then trying to grab the month by name but failed miserably, any help is appreciated!

I'm assuming I'll have to **GROUP BY** the **SELECT** result from the orders date?

This is Oracle SQL

Tried query

```
SELECT Clientte.nm_cliente, Item_pedido.nr_quantidade "Quantidade", Pedido.dt_venda 
FROM Clientte INNER JOIN Pedido
ON Clientte.id_cliente = Pedido.id_cliente
INNER JOIN Item_pedido
ON Pedido.id_pedido = item_pedido.id_pedido
INNER JOIN Produto
ON item_pedido.id_produto= Produto.id_Produto;
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the query that is not working. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). [edit] your question, do **not** post code in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want something like this.

```
SELECT to_char(Pedido.dt_venda, 'Month') as mon, 
    Clientte.nm_cliente, 
    count(distinct id_pedido) as num_orders,
    sum(Item_pedido.nr_quantidade * produto.nr_preco) total_value 
FROM Clientte 
INNER JOIN Pedido
  ON Clientte.id_cliente = Pedido.id_cliente
INNER JOIN Item_pedido
  ON Pedido.id_pedido = item_pedido.id_pedido
INNER JOIN Produto
  ON item_pedido.id_produto= Produto.id_Produto
GROUP BY to_char(Pedido.dt_venda, 'Month');
```

Two assumptions - you say you want "the quantity of orders", so I'm assuming you mean the number of unique ID_PEDIDOs for that month. You might instead want `sum(nr_quantidade)`, the total number of items ordered, I'm not sure.

Second, you want "the total value of order", which I'm assuming means the total item quantity * price for all items in each order.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Count(*), ID_PEDIDO, EXTRACT(month FROM date) FROM Pedido 
GROUP BY ID_PEDIDO, EXTRACT(month FROM date)
```

Can you see if this gets you closer?

Comment: That got me a lot closer to getting the months name, thanks! Have any idea how I would go about grouping the orders by month now?